# Как из заголовочного файла .h обратиться к элементу формы, описаной в Form1.h?

Tags: .net, winforms, c++, visual-studio

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Проект Windows Form, Visual Studio C++.

У меня есть файл `ClassNeuronNet.h`, в котором описан класс, имеющий метод `teach()` и форма проекта Form1.h, в которой есть директива `#include "ClassNeuronNet.h"`.

Как из метода `teach()` обратиться к элементу формы, например, к свойству `Text` метки `Label1 (Label->Text)`?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include "Form1.h"
```

В файл **ClassNeuronNet.cpp**

Хотя это не очень красиво. Красивее класс с методом teach инициализировать разделяемым объектом (некоторого класса, например под названием DataBuffer) с классом Form1.